# Outlook 2010 Send on Behalf problem

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm having a problem in Outlook 2010 where I cannot send emails on behalf of another person using the AutoSuggest feature.

I can send the first email on behalf of a person by finding their name in the Global Address Book. His name is then added to the list of suggested names for easier access next time.

If I were to select his name from the Suggested List, instead of going to the Global Address Book, my email is not sent and is returned to me saying I don't have the proper permissions.

We've already set up the proper permissions that I can send on behalf of this person and we're not sure what else to do.

Comment: What version of Exchange is this using?

Comment: They're using exchange 2003.